# Report Lab Text Issues when add & symbol

Tags: reportlab

I had Paragraph like these

Paragraph("****test&SC-1420****", styleN)

while Pdf Generation I got Output like  **test&SC-1420;**  i didnt use semicolon it generate auto

Comment: try `Paragraph("test&amp;SC-1420", styleN)`

Comment: I got It bro works fine. Thanks for your message.

Answer (score 1):

Paragraph text can contain html so it is parsed by `ParaParser` which is subclass of `HTMLParser` so it tries to decode html entites. If text contains `<` or `>` or `&` you have to convert them to entites first: `&lt;` `&gt;` `&amp;`.